# Can't build C/C++ projects using maven-nar plugin

Tags: maven, maven-nar-plugin

I'm trying to setup a simple project with an empty function (.c and .h file) on windows 7, using maven, cygwin and gcc. Following are details about my environment:

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 22:51:28+0900)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.6.0_37, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\jre
Default locale: ko_KR, platform encoding: MS949
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
gcc (GCC) 4.5.3
```

When I try to build using the maven-nar plugin, I get the following error:

```
$ mvn clean package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-maven 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ test-maven ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-nar-plugin:2.1-SNAPSHOT:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) @ test-maven ---
[INFO] Using AOL: x86-Windows-msvc
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.600s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 30 18:03:18 KST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-nar-plugin:2.1-SNAPSHOT:nar-validate (default-nar-validate) on project test-maven: Cannot deduce version number from: -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I have google'd and it seems to be related to maven not finding the `gcc` compiler.

```
Cannot deduce version number from: -> [Help 1]
```

The output from the `mvn` command also suggests that maven is trying to build my project with `msvc` which is not available on my machine.

```
[INFO] Using AOL: x86-Windows-msvc
```

I have the `gcc` compiler in my path etc and I have tried to follow some of the steps suggested in [this very old thread](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NAR-150?focusedCommentId=180398&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-180398).

Does anyone know how to overcome this problem? If I'm in the wrong forum, could someone please point me to the right one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that error is caused by a command line tool being unavailable on the path. However, in this case, since your AOL is `x86-Windows-msvc`, the relevant command line tool is `link`, not `gcc`. (You can see this in [the source code](https://github.com/maven-nar/maven-nar-plugin/blob/5889a13d495beaca6ad1362672d45f2ba477c261/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/nar/Linker.java#L203).)

Of course, you aren't trying to use the MSVC compiler at all, so you shouldn't need `link` in your path anyway. To use `gcc` instead, you need to configure that in your POM in the `maven-nar-plugin` configuration. Here is a sample configuration (from [this project](https://github.com/imagej/imagej/blob/e36e91145b3f13d3759b8b920e792bcfb15dcc4f/launcher/pom.xml#L53), which you will of course need to tweak to your needs):

```
<configuration>
    <c>
        <name>gcc</name>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.c</include>
        </includes>
        <options>
            <option>-I${JAVA_HOME}/include</option>
            <option>${java.os.include}</option>
            <option>${stack.protector.option}</option>
            <option>${architecture.option}</option>
            <option>${subsystem.option}</option>
            <option>${debug.option}</option>
        </options>
    </c>
    <linker>
        <name>gcc</name>
        <options>
            <option>${architecture.option}</option>
            <option>${subsystem.option}</option>
        </options>
        <sysLibs>
            <sysLib>
                <name>${libdl.name}</name>
            </sysLib>
        </sysLibs>
    </linker>
    <libraries>
        <library>
            <type>executable</type>
            <!-- <run>true</run> -->
            <subSystem>gui</subSystem>
        </library>
    </libraries>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You really did help me out. I've been stuck on this for quite a few days.

Comment: I put a live example on https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/example-maven-project-setups.

Comment: Thanks, I linked it from the NAR wiki! https://github.com/maven-nar/nar-maven-plugin/wiki/Working-examples